# Is Final Fantasy XI still playable online from a PS2?

Tags: ps2, final-fantasy-11

I have a PS2 Slim, and I'm collecting all FF games. This may seem like a silly/ignorant question, but it is FFXI still online?

As in, can I still play it online from my old PS2?

Comment: As far as I know, FFXI status as a game hasn't changed since I last played it a few years ago. It's still a MMORPG.

Comment: Is it even possible for him to play this on his slim PS2? Originally you had to install a hard drive into your original (fat) PS2 to play FFXI. Does a slim PS2 allow you to install a hard drive?

Comment: @UnknownZombie Doesn't look like it. For what I can gather from [google](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ip5sVcjmEeSM8QfTmoGIAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=final%20fantasy%2011%20ps2%20slim), you need a version of the ps2 with a hhd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FF11 is still online.  Support on PS2 and Xbox 360 will end in March 2016. ([Source](http://forum.square-enix.com/ffxi/threads/46414-Conference-Digest))

Comment: Just a note: The game will still be available for PC users after March 2016.  After this time though, the game as a whole will stop production of the usual large content updates as the game. (A whole 13 years of content!)

In the MMO community, we usual call this Maintenance Mode for games as they're still online but most of the devs are off the project or running with the bare minimum to keep it alive.